# How to secure switch box flush with wall surface

Tags: drywall, receptacle, installation

Today I removed all the outlet covers in my home, and when I got to my bedroom light switch I noticed there was all this wood surrounding the switch itself. I tore that off as well, and after I did so I realized it was on there because the box that the outlet sits inside of is completely sinking into the wall.

When I try to screw the switch back into the wall it goes almost sideways. How can I fix this? I can almost completely pull the box out of the wall. Is this something simple like cutting the wall back and placing a strip behind it and then repairing the drywall, or is it something more complicated?

Comment: Well Dwayne...it would be helpful if you could use your phone and take a couple of clear pictures of this one switch box and then post them here. Then maybe someone would be able to actually provide some sort of answer.

Comment: A "goof ring" might help, but without photos who could say...

Comment: A: Take pictures and post. B: tearing things off without taking the time to understand why they are there in the first place can be a very bad and/or expensive idea...

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely easily fixed by swapping the box out with a different style (Old Work Box) or simply running some screws into the side of the existing box if it's against a stud, depending on the situation.

Pictures will help.

Either way, it's unlikely that you will have to cut into the wall.

a) Here is how to remove an broken electrical box:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qq4UkWsUWoo

b) And here is how to install an "old work box" in its place:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8Fq8I_AQ-Q